# How copy element of sorted set to other sorted set?

Tags: php, redis

There are a two `sorted sets` in Redis store with scores (timestamp).
How I can copy one *element* from `sorted set` and insert to other?

I think this should be like as:

```
$time = time();
$key = 'set1';
$key2 = 'set2';

$data = $redis->zRangeByScore($key, $time, $time); // Get one element by score timestamp

$redis->zAdd($key2, $time, $data);
```

Comment: What is the outcome? Do you see an error? Did the result not match your expectation?

Comment: It works, I was not sure about code. Thanks